# Can't start latest WAMP and XAMPP?

Tags: php, apache, server, xampp, wamp

I can't start WAMP 2.5 and XAMPP 7 but I can start WAMP 2.2 so its not port 80 issue ( I have listed all programs with netstat in cmd ). I have run httpd.exe in cmd but it didn't give me useful information on cmd ( nothing ).

Thanks for the answer

Comment: Make sure you start the httpd (almost) as the service would would via `bin\httpd.exe -f path\to\httpd.conf`. Do you get errors then? Is there something in the windows event log regarding the httpd?

Comment: Any error messages ? Otherwise we can only guess

Comment: Nope, no error messages showed on cmd      http://postimg.org/image/l6xh9hl2f/

Comment: Not sure how to use event log, but here's the list of events right after the error   http://postimg.org/image/xhkk4wp9l/

Comment: The more interesting information is in the detail view below the part in the screenshot. The errors regarding the service control manager look interesting, though actual errors of the httpd should be logged with the source "httpd".

Comment: Here it is http://postimg.org/image/u7ezjsn3h/  , by the way I just invoked that error again but nothing was added to the list there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your port and try once

Edit your `httpd.conf` in XAMPP

Change this to

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80 
Listen 80
```

this

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80 
Listen 85
```

Then access your localhost useing

```
localhost:85/
```

[image: xampp]

---

If its same open cmd and type `netstat -nab` and check whats showing with port 80

Comment: "but I can start WAMP 2.2 so its not port 80 issue ( I have listed all programs with netstat in cmd )."

Comment: @VolkerK ya i saw. Some time this will occur. One of my mate struggle with same manner. So i did this. Its fine