# XAMPP - Apache and MySQL

Tags: mysql, apache, server, xampp, htdocs

I'm trying to run `Apache` and `MySQL` on XAMPP Control Panel v.3.2.2, but it doesn't want to start.

I googled and it was mostly because port was already in used(usually because Skype is using it), but I re-mark that function in Skype and it's still the same.

I'm not sure if I'm using it anywhere else - I do not as far as I know - or it's something else.

XAMPP installation is fresh, I've never installed it before.

This is the error that I get:

> 11:31:48  [Apache]    Attempting to start Apache app... 
>   11:31:48  [Apache]    Status change detected: running 
>   11:31:49  [Apache]    Status change detected: stopped 
>   11:31:49  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly. 
>   11:31:49  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
>   11:31:49  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method. 
>   11:31:49  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
>   11:31:49  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
>   11:31:49  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this 
>   11:31:49  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache is not running from XAMPP Control Panel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946150/apache-is-not-running-from-xampp-control-panel)

Comment: You should check the apache log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change these

**Method 01 - Change XAMPP port**

In your `httpd.conf`

Change port like this

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80 
Listen 85
```

Then access localhost by using

```
localhost:85/
```

[Check this answer too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34962127/4595675)

---

**Method 02 - Change Skype Port**

Go to **`Tools/Option/Advanced/Connections`** and ***uncheck*** the box "***`use port 80 and 443 as alternative`***".

Comment: I did all of it, but it's not changing. Also, when I type netstat -nab in cmd it says "The requested operation requires elevation".

Comment: @Seinfeld happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can click the **netstat** on the XAMMP and see which services are using the ports needed for Apache and mysql.
Then go to the **services** (which you can get when you simply search on the start menu) and **stop the service** which is using the necessary port and try to start Apache and mysql from XAMMP.

The required ports were being blocked by vmware in my case, simply stopping the vmware workstations service solved the situation for me.